# Does Kaneki die in season 2?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Because some people say that Haise is just a new character. I just want information because I'm confused.

Comment: i am assuming you were talking about tokyo ghoul as that was the only series which which i knew of a character named Kaneki

Comment: yes and im wonder if i did happen and its in tokyoo ghoul

Comment: Tokyo Ghoul the manga ended a long time ago, with a similar plot (but completely different events) including an ambiguous did Kaneki Die end scene (highly recommend you read the manga, at minimum from the end of season 1, if not from chapter 1 to correct the changes in the anime). Then and only then can you fully understand its sequal, RE: which will have the answers you seek.

Comment: Please, read manga if you want to know plot details. Your question was answered in Tokyo Ghould: RE long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Spoilers for those that haven't seen the show.

> When Kaneki was trying to live as a human his hair was black, then when he decided to cross into the world of ghouls, his hair went white. While living amonst the ghouls his hair remained white. Following this, at the end of the series his hair starts to turn black again as he crosses back to the side of the humans. Now, as Haise Sasaki, who lives as something between humans and ghouls, his hair is white with black in it. There is clear visual symoblism that proves they are the same character. Not to mention plot I don't want to spoil.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are talking about Tokyo Ghoul. In the manga (at the place where season 2 of the anime ended), Arima kills Kaneki and stabs him in the eye. Kaneki does "die", but as tha manga continues,

POSSIBLE SPOILERS FOR SEASON 3!

> Kaneki "comes back" as Haise Sasaki with little to no memory, so techinically, he didn't comepletely die. In the anime, it never shows Kaneki's fight with Arima at the end of season 2, but if there is going to be a season 3 which continues from where season 2 left off, then we can safetly *assume* that Kaneki did get killed by Arima.

Comment: Your spoiler answers the question then contradicts itself.